# Number keeps on generating ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

My intention is to produce only one random number but it keeps on jumping different random number even without even refreshing my page.

Here are my codes:

**random.ts**

```
get random(){

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*20)+1;

return rand;       
}
```

**random.html**

```
ion-card-content class="random"> {{random}} /ion-card-content>
```

Is there any way to just produce on random number?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is your desired lifetime for the random number -- anyone who ever uses your program gets the same number every time (in which case you should just roll a die and hard code the number); or anyone who uses your program gets the same random number per-use of the program, but different for each use? In that case you need a static object. The random number could be global, and set just once during initialization.

Comment: I was planning to generate a random number once every page as i am doing an ordering application which requires a queue number for the customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must never call a method like you did inside the Angular interpolation. Because it executes each and every time when Angular's change detection life cycle. So you can do it like this:

*.ts*

```
myRand: number;

ionViewDidEnter() {
   this.myRand=this.random();
  }

 random(): number {
   let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*20)+1;
   return rand;       
}
```

*.html*

```
<p> {{myRand}} </p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out, I am kinda new to ionic 3 so forgive me if my coding is kind of lousy.. thank you once again!!